# AngularJS - scope variable syntax in html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In AngularJS, 
I want to use a scope variable defined in Javascript as 'propertySkipCount' in the HTML. I tried with {{propertySkipCount}} and also directly as propertySkipCount, but both does not work.

It only works if I substitute the variable with value like 1.

**Javascript**

```
 $scope.propertySkipCount = 1;
```

**HTML**

```
                <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="property in entity.entityPropertyTypes" ng-if="$index > propertySkipCount">



                <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="property in entity.entityPropertyTypes" ng-if="$index > {{propertySkipCount}}">
```

**Update:**

I want the code to look like below after substitution. If I hard code like below it works.

```
 <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="property in entity.entityPropertyTypes" ng-if="$index > 1">
```

**Plunker**

http://plnkr.co/edit/wMKa1dbeVNz3WfUojmjR?p=info

Comment: 1st method should work. Can your create a plunker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first method is works fine please check

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="property in entity.entityPropertyTypes" ng-if="$index > propertySkipCount">
```

Comment: He wants the variable inside ng-if and not print it in html.

Comment: Thanks will add Plunker.. vachitaanya aapu

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="property in entity.entityPropertyTypes" ng-if="$index > propertySkipCount"> Test {{propertySkipCount}}</div>
```

Above code should work.

Comment: Thanks, that's just a code fragment I put. I have already closed in my application.

Answer (score 1):

code looks fine  . It should work , problem maybe with **version** you are currently using .

**view:**

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="property in entityPropertyTypes" ng-if="$index > propertySkipCount">Hello ...! ++  {{$index}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

works fine with **[Angular 1.2.1](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/20242/)**

Not working as expected with **[Angular 1.1.1](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/20243/)**

Comment: Thanks I am using Angular 1.4.6

Comment: @Jay glad i could help buddie . are you sure you marked the right one as answer . cheers